# Like in the comments didn't work and return json page response `{"a_c_like": true}`

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I build the comment system and when I click like in the first comment the like appears successfully but when I come to the next comment It returns the JSON response page `{"a_c_like": true}` instead of like appear and the like count in the span also didn't work (count). I build my comment system on the **MPTTModel**

my view

```
def add_like_to_comment(request, id):
comment = Comment.objects.get(id=id)
data = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    account = request.user
    if comment.likes.filter(id=account.id).exists():
        comment.likes.remove(account)
        a_c_like = False
    else:
        comment.likes.add(account)
        a_c_like = True

data["a_c_like"] = a_c_like
print(data)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

my urls

```
  path('comment/like/<int:id>/like', add_like_to_comment, name='add_like_to_comment'),
```

the html template

```
      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'video:add_like_to_comment' node.id %}" id="comment-like-form">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <button style="color: #aaaaaa;"  class="remove-default-btn  p-0 border-0 " type="submit"  style="border: none; color: #aaaaaa;" >

            <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16" >
              <path d="M8 2.748l-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
            <span class="ml-1"  >{{ node.likes.all.count }}</span></svg>

        </button>
    </form>
```

Ajax file which handles the like comments

```
    $("#comment-like-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    let url = form.attr("action");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            var btn = form.find("button[type='submit']");

            if (response.a_c_like) {

                btn.css("color", "red");

            } else {
                btn.css("color", "#aaaaaa");
            }
            btn.find("span").text(response.count)
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using "**response.count**" but you didn't pass the count value.

add data["count"] = comment.likes.count() in your views.py

example:

```
def add_like_to_comment(request, id):
comment = Comment.objects.get(id=id)
data = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    account = request.user
    if comment.likes.filter(id=account.id).exists():
        comment.likes.remove(account)
        a_c_like = False
    else:
        comment.likes.add(account)
        a_c_like = True

data["a_c_like"] = a_c_like
data["count"] = comment.likes.count()
print(data)
return JsonResponse(data)
```